# Delphi - unit 'Classes' included but can't find function 'FindComponent'

Tags: delphi

I've created a simple class and got a little problem:
I just want to use the method "findComponent' from the classes-unit.
I've included the classes unit, but Delphi can't find the findComponent-method.
Why? I'm sure that's a very simple problem...

```
unit U_Test;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, QStdCtrls;

type
  TTest = Class
  public
    //
  private
    procedure test();
  End;

implementation

procedure TTest.test();
begin
  FindControl('test');    // FindControl is found in unit controls
  FindComponent('test');  // FindComponent is NOT found, but unit classes is included
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SimaWB said `FindComponent`  is a method in the `TComponent` class.

If you want to access that method, inherit TComponent class.

```
  TTest = Class(TComponent)
  public
    //
  private
    procedure test();
  End;
```

Answer (score 11):

Because FindComponent is the function of TComponent class. But your TTest class base on TObject by default.